# Entitymanager works chaotically, do not merge in some cases

Tags: eclipselink, vaadin, entitymanager, chaos

Seriously, i cannot believe this:

I use entityManager in Vaadin framework. Implemented this pattern (ThreadLocal and filter for generating entityManager for every request):

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/jpacontainer.hibernate.html

If i write a test it is works like charm:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("applicLiquidator.applicLiquidator");
log.trace("created entityManageFactory:" + entityManagerFactory);
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

CaseEntity case= entityManager.getReference(CaseEntity .class, 1);
entityManager.detach(case);
case.setCompanyFullName("TEST1");

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
CaseEntity newCase=entityManager.merge(case);
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

However in the application server it works entirely other way, i logged ever information and seems everything is OK, the entity has the good values!

```
   public static int saveCase(CaseEntity case, boolean sameTransaction) throws DALException {
        EntityTransaction transaction = null;
        try {
            EntityManager entityManager = EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManagerLIQUIDATOR();
            if (sameTransaction == false) {
                transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
                transaction.begin();
            }
                      log.info("-------BEFORE PERSIST: CASE ENTTIY COMAPNY NAME: " + ugy.getFelszamolandoCegTeljesnev());
        ugy=entityManager.merge(ugy);
        if (sameTransaction == false) {
            transaction.commit();
        }

        log.info("---------AFTER PERSIST: CASE ENTTIY COMAPNY NAME: " + ugy.getFelszamolandoCegTeljesnev());  
            return case.getId();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("The entity saved do not completed", ex);
            try {
                transaction.rollback();
                log.info("Rollback was success");
            } catch (Exception rollbex) {
                log.error("Rollback failed", rollbex);
            }
            log.info("Entity Saved succesfully!");
            throw new DALException(ex);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, i tried refresh, clear, flush everything. Important to note here that case is a detached object, but as far as i know merge will do the job but the reference will not copied to the original object, but will (should) update the entity with the same id...

In other cases (with other entites this code is works like charm), only with one case, the first one entity at the database with id 1 is making bug!

I cannot understand why it is, why it is working some cases, and why it is not... And why it is that **i see the good values in the entity attibutes** and it just doesn't generate the update sql and doesn't make the merge/update in the persistance context and also at the database, no error message, nothing to show, only missfunction...

If anyone ever experience this kind of mistic bug/issue i would more than appreciate the answer or any slight idea, anything came in to your mind pls take time to answer.

Log when try to merge entity:

```
2014-01-21 17:36:11 TRACE LazyEntityManagerFilter:44 - created entityManager:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@7b1fe9fb
2014-01-21 17:36:11 WARN  UgyController:667 - Event detected private void notImplemented()
2014-01-21 17:36:11 TRACE LazyEntityManagerFilter:51 - destroyed entityManager:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@7b1fe9fb
2014-01-21 17:36:11 TRACE LazyEntityManagerFilter:44 - created entityManager:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.387--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, becsultertek, bekerulesidopontja, devizanem, ingosagazonosito, kikerulesidopontja, kikerulesiertek, letrehozva, megnevezes, memo, tarolasihely, telephelyenbelulihelye, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, telephely_felszamolando_ID, ingosagcsoport_ID, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.ingosag WHERE (telephely_felszamolando_ID = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.389--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, csoportnev, letrehozva, lockideje, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID, lockbyfelhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.ingosagcsoport WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.392--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, csoportnev, letrehozva, lockideje, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID, lockbyfelhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.ingosagcsoport WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [2]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.394--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, bejelentkezesidopontja, bejelentkezesinev, email, jelszo, keresztnev, kilepesideje, letrehozva, lockideje, memo, sessionlejarat, szerepkor, telefon, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, vezeteknev, cim_ID, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID, bejelentkezes_telephelyId, lockbyfelhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.felhasznalo WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [3]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.398--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, fajlnev, kiskeptartalom, letrehozva, memo, mimetype, nincskep, tartalom, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, ingosag_ID, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.kep WHERE (ingosag_ID = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.4--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, fajlnev, kiskeptartalom, letrehozva, memo, mimetype, nincskep, tartalom, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, ingosag_ID, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.kep WHERE (ingosag_ID = ?)
    bind => [2]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.401--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, becsultertek, bekerulesidopontja, devizanem, ingosagazonosito, kikerulesidopontja, kikerulesiertek, letrehozva, megnevezes, memo, tarolasihely, telephelyenbelulihelye, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, telephely_felszamolando_ID, ingosagcsoport_ID, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.ingosag WHERE (telephely_felszamolando_ID = ?)
    bind => [2]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.402--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, becsultertek, bekerulesidopontja, devizanem, ingosagazonosito, kikerulesidopontja, kikerulesiertek, letrehozva, megnevezes, memo, tarolasihely, telephelyenbelulihelye, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, telephely_felszamolando_ID, ingosagcsoport_ID, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.ingosag WHERE (telephely_felszamolando_ID = ?)
    bind => [3]
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.404--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, belsougyiratszam, elrendeles_doc_fajlnev, elrendeles_doc_memo, elrendeles_doc_mimetype, elrendeles_doc_tartalom, elrendeles_idopontja, elrendeles_ki, elrendeles_memo, felszamolando_ceg_adoszam, felszamolando_ceg_cegjegyzekszam, felszamolando_ceg_memo, felszamolando_ceg_rovidnev, felszamolando_ceg_teljesnev, kozzeteteldatuma, kulsougyiratszam, letrehozva, lockideje, memo, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, zarovegzesdatuma, elrendeles_felhasznalo_ID, ugy_felhasznalo_ID, felszamolando_ceg_cim_ID, telephely_ID, statusz_ID, ugytipus_ID, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID, lockbyfelhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.ugy WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (aktiv = ?))
    bind => [7, true]
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.41--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, letrehozva, lockideje, statusz, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID, lockbyfelhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.ugystatusz WHERE (aktiv = ?)
    bind => [true]
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.413--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT DISTINCT f.* FROM felhasznalo f,telephely, felhasznalougyintezo_telephely ftu WHERE f.aktiv = 1 AND telephely.ID = ? AND telephely.aktiv = 1 AND f.ID = ftu.felhasznalo_ID AND ftu.telephely_ID = ?
    bind => [1, 1]
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.418--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, letrehozva, lockideje, tipus, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID, lockbyfelhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.ugytipus WHERE (aktiv = ?)
    bind => [true]
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.421--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT DISTINCT f.* FROM felhasznalo f,telephely, felhasznalougyintezo_telephely ftu WHERE f.aktiv = 1 AND telephely.ID = ? AND telephely.aktiv = 1 AND f.ID = ftu.felhasznalo_ID AND ftu.telephely_ID = ?
    bind => [1, 1]
telephelyTelephely A
telephelyTelephely B
telephelyTelephely (törölt)
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.449--ClientSession(1062469667)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--UPDATE liquidator.felhasznalo SET bejelentkezes_telephelyId = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [1, 9999999]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.45--ClientSession(1062469667)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--UPDATE liquidator.telephely_felszamolando SET tranzakcioskod = ?, utoljaramod_mikor = ?, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [8d7b4195-38f3-4ba6-ab13-2840de6291d4, 2014-01-21 17:36:11.384, 9999999, 1]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.452--ClientSession(1062469667)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--UPDATE liquidator.telephely_felszamolando SET tranzakcioskod = ?, utoljaramod_mikor = ?, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [8d7b4195-38f3-4ba6-ab13-2840de6291d4, 2014-01-21 17:36:11.384, 9999999, 2]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.453--ClientSession(1062469667)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--UPDATE liquidator.telephely_felszamolando SET tranzakcioskod = ?, utoljaramod_mikor = ?, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [8d7b4195-38f3-4ba6-ab13-2840de6291d4, 2014-01-21 17:36:11.384, 9999999, 3]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.467--ClientSession(1062469667)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--UPDATE liquidator.ingosag SET tranzakcioskod = ?, utoljaramod_mikor = ?, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [8d7b4195-38f3-4ba6-ab13-2840de6291d4, 2014-01-21 17:36:11.384, 9999999, 1]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.468--ClientSession(1062469667)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--UPDATE liquidator.ingosag SET tranzakcioskod = ?, utoljaramod_mikor = ?, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [8d7b4195-38f3-4ba6-ab13-2840de6291d4, 2014-01-21 17:36:11.384, 9999999, 2]
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  UgyController$UgyPersistor:978 - UgyEntity módosítása a DB-ben sikeres. UgyEntityID: 7
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.524--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, belsougyiratszam, elrendeles_doc_fajlnev, elrendeles_doc_memo, elrendeles_doc_mimetype, elrendeles_doc_tartalom, elrendeles_idopontja, elrendeles_ki, elrendeles_memo, felszamolando_ceg_adoszam, felszamolando_ceg_cegjegyzekszam, felszamolando_ceg_memo, felszamolando_ceg_rovidnev, felszamolando_ceg_teljesnev, kozzeteteldatuma, kulsougyiratszam, letrehozva, lockideje, memo, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, zarovegzesdatuma, elrendeles_felhasznalo_ID, ugy_felhasznalo_ID, felszamolando_ceg_cim_ID, telephely_ID, statusz_ID, ugytipus_ID, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID, lockbyfelhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.ugy WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (aktiv = ?))
    bind => [7, true]
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  UgyController$UgyPersistor:998 - Ügy egészének perzisztálása sikeres. UgyEntityID: 7
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.528--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, belsougyiratszam, elrendeles_doc_fajlnev, elrendeles_doc_memo, elrendeles_doc_mimetype, elrendeles_doc_tartalom, elrendeles_idopontja, elrendeles_ki, elrendeles_memo, felszamolando_ceg_adoszam, felszamolando_ceg_cegjegyzekszam, felszamolando_ceg_memo, felszamolando_ceg_rovidnev, felszamolando_ceg_teljesnev, kozzeteteldatuma, kulsougyiratszam, letrehozva, lockideje, memo, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, zarovegzesdatuma, elrendeles_felhasznalo_ID, ugy_felhasznalo_ID, felszamolando_ceg_cim_ID, telephely_ID, statusz_ID, ugytipus_ID, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID, lockbyfelhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.ugy WHERE (aktiv = ?)
    bind => [true]
2014-01-21 17:36:11 INFO  EntityManagerUtil:46 - entityManager object name@hascode:org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@6c3a9ce3
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:36:11.54--ServerSession(2071159129)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-19,5,main])--SELECT ID, aktiv, belsougyiratszam, elrendeles_doc_fajlnev, elrendeles_doc_memo, elrendeles_doc_mimetype, elrendeles_doc_tartalom, elrendeles_idopontja, elrendeles_ki, elrendeles_memo, felszamolando_ceg_adoszam, felszamolando_ceg_cegjegyzekszam, felszamolando_ceg_memo, felszamolando_ceg_rovidnev, felszamolando_ceg_teljesnev, kozzeteteldatuma, kulsougyiratszam, letrehozva, lockideje, memo, tranzakcioskod, utoljaramod_mikor, zarovegzesdatuma, elrendeles_felhasznalo_ID, ugy_felhasznalo_ID, felszamolando_ceg_cim_ID, telephely_ID, statusz_ID, ugytipus_ID, utoljaramodositotta_felhasznalo_ID, lockbyfelhasznalo_ID FROM liquidator.ugy WHERE ((ID = ?) AND (aktiv = ?))

bind => [7, true]
```

But when i want to save/merge another entity (e.g. ID 1303), the insert is nicely generated and executed:

```
  [EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:38:19.391--ClientSession(1093415948)--Connection(264299847)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-22,5,main])--UPDATE liquidator.ugy SET felszamolando_ceg_teljesnev = ?, lockideje = ?, tranzakcioskod = ?, utoljaramod_mikor = ?, lockbyfelhasznalo_ID = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
        bind => [akgalkgsafafsTESTESTUJUJ, null, 52254092-4954-441f-922c-8c5527b9dd9a, 2014-01-21 17:38:19.368, null, 1303]
```

**LOG UPDATE WITH NEW CODE**

```
2014-01-21 17:55:19 INFO  UgyDAO:162 - -------BEFORE PERSIST: CASE ENTTIY COMAPNY NAME: NEW COMPANY NAME
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:55:19.19--ClientSession(1760590618)--Connection(392035700)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-46,5,main])--UPDATE liquidator.telephely_felszamolando SET tranzakcioskod = ?, utoljaramod_mikor = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [fe48707b-5064-49c5-81bf-d1f78cd93126, 2014-01-21 17:55:19.156, 1]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:55:19.194--ClientSession(1760590618)--Connection(392035700)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-46,5,main])--UPDATE liquidator.telephely_felszamolando SET tranzakcioskod = ?, utoljaramod_mikor = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [fe48707b-5064-49c5-81bf-d1f78cd93126, 2014-01-21 17:55:19.156, 2]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:55:19.197--ClientSession(1760590618)--Connection(392035700)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-46,5,main])--UPDATE liquidator.telephely_felszamolando SET tranzakcioskod = ?, utoljaramod_mikor = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [fe48707b-5064-49c5-81bf-d1f78cd93126, 2014-01-21 17:55:19.156, 3]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:55:19.198--ClientSession(1760590618)--Connection(392035700)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-46,5,main])--UPDATE liquidator.ingosag SET tranzakcioskod = ?, utoljaramod_mikor = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [fe48707b-5064-49c5-81bf-d1f78cd93126, 2014-01-21 17:55:19.156, 1]
[EL Fine]: 2014-01-21 17:55:19.201--ClientSession(1760590618)--Connection(392035700)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-46,5,main])--UPDATE liquidator.ingosag SET tranzakcioskod = ?, utoljaramod_mikor = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [fe48707b-5064-49c5-81bf-d1f78cd93126, 2014-01-21 17:55:19.156, 2]
2014-01-21 17:55:19 INFO  UgyDAO:168 - ---------AFTER PERSIST: CASE ENTTIY COMAPNY NAME: UJ TELJES NEV!
```

Comment: If case is detached, and you cleared the EM, why are you calling entityManager.refresh(case); and entityManager.flush(); before the merge call?  Refresh should result in an IllegalArgumentException if the entity isn't managed, so something else is going on.

Comment: Sorry, the code is bad, because i translate the entities name, fixed it. appreciate your comment!

Comment: And i just tried everything i got, because i see at the debug console and log also, that the entity is changed but merge just DO NOTHING... Can not understand why. Want to force somehow to make an update

Comment: So prior to merge, oldCase and case are different.  After merge, what is in case?  Did the changes get copied correctly, or is it just that the database doesn't get updated?  What is happening in the logs (turn on your JPA provider logging if you haven't already)?

Comment: I turned on the logging already. Thanks for your helping! The case after the merging is that the case is get values from the database, no insert or update sql is executed. I will edit my answer to contains the logs from the button push to the merge... (And i will fastly answer after this)

Comment: I do not understand why it is but it seem, JPA entitymanager feels NOTHING is changed in this particular case!!! ANd if i manually change same attribute than it feels... Tried it!

Comment: I updated my code with a log.info("") to write out particular attribute... I never ever seee this thing, i feel this method is buggy... Or do not know what is go wrong, how to tell entityManager that this entity is a new, not an old one??!?!

Comment: One more adding: If i do not detach the entity, then the entityManager feel the changed attribute!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very believe however yet no time to POC/test it, but my problem was caused because the poorly implemented hashcode() and equals() methods!

As it seems reference this article:
http://tmjee.blogspot.hu/2012/11/do-we-need-equals-and-hashcode.html

That poor hashcode implementation can cause merge problems in detached objects, and that is exactly my issue.